# Sortable ListView in Apache WIcket

Tags: wicket

I have successfully displayed data in tabular form using ListView. However, I wanted it to be sortable. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm.. Perhaps [DefaultDataTable](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/DefaultDataTable.html) could have been better suited for your use case of displaying tabular data in a sortable fashion. Let me know if you need more explanation or a code example.

Comment: Some basic examples are available from https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/simple-sortable-datatable-example.html and https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/simple-sortable-datatable-example.html If you have any specific questions regarding implementation feel free to either update your question or write a new one.

Comment: These lines are giving out errors saying that there should be no paramaters:

    PropertyModel<Comparable> model1 = new   PropertyModel<Comparable>(o1, getSort().getProperty());
    PropertyModel<Comparable> model2 = new  PropertyModel<Comparable>(o2, getSort().getProperty());

Comment: I got the example to work. My problem now is my own implementation where I may have to refactor the existing code made by others just to integrate sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort the List that you pass to ListView.
Something like:

```
final SortState sort = SortState.ByName;
add(new ListView(id, new AbstractReadOnlyModel<ArrayList<Person>>() {
   public ArrayList<Person> getObject() {
     ArrayList<Person> list = makeList();
     Comparator<Person> comparator = getComparator(sort);
     Collections.sort(comparator, list);
     return list;
   }
});

add(new Link(sortByAgeLinkId) {
  public void onClick() { sort = SortState.ByAge;}
});
```

... more links for different criteria.